# How to compare dates with different timezones in moment.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, timezone, momentjs

My server's date format is in `UTC`. I am running my node server in UTC format. I wanna check whether the current time is greater than 8AM in `Indian timezone` i.e +5.30 and should send a mail. How can I identify this using `moment.js`

Comment: This functionality has been split into moment-timezone. You can find docs here http://momentjs.com/timezone/

Answer (score 9):

Using [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/):

```
if (moment.tz("08:00","HH:mm","Asia/Kolkata").isBefore()) {
  // ...
}
```

Or, since India does not use daylight saving time, you actually don't need moment-timezone.  You just need to specify the fixed offset correctly.  Other zones that use DST or have other base-offset transitions to consider will indeed need moment-timezone.

```
if (moment.parseZone("08:00+05:30","HH:mmZ").isBefore()) {
  // ...
}
```

With both of the above, keep in mind that `isBefore` will default to the current time when there are no parameters.  You could write it using `moment().isAfter(...)`, instead, but it's slightly shorter the other way.

It doesn't matter whether you compare against UTC or local time because internally moment is tracking the instantaneous UTC-based value anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`isAfter`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-after/) and  [Moment Timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/):

```
// Get server date with moment, in the example serverTime = current UTC time
var serverDate = moment.utc();
// Get time in India with Moment Timezone
var indiaDate = moment.tz("Asia/Kolkata");
// Setting time to 8:00 AM (I'm supposing you need to compare with the current day)
indiaDate.hours(8).minutes(0).seconds(0);
if( serverDate.isAfter(indiaDate) ){
    // Server date is greater than 8 AM in India
    // Add here the code to send a mail
}
```